# Normal derivative of derivated variable not working in Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, maple

I have done this and I really have no idea what is wrong with Maple. Here is the equation and the Maple respond:

[image]

The text of error is: `Error, invalid input: diff received diff(theta1(t), t), which is not valid for its 2nd argument`.

I have no idea how to solve the equation…

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling it as,

```
Physics:-diff(L, ...);
```

instead of as,

```
diff(L, ...);
```